# Issue creating table partition by date with data from other table. In Google Cloud

Tags: sql, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, database-partitioning

I'm doing a course from Google. Modernizing Data Lakes and Data Warehouses. And in the quest they ask to create a partition table and populate all the info from the source table, I execute my code, the table is created but empty.
I also try to create empty table and next insert, and also no info in my table., in this case the log says that are inserted: XXX lines. But when I check the preview, or I query a SELECT *, my table is still empty.
Please, why is happening this? Help!

```
#standardSQL
CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE
  covid_598.oxford_policy_tracker_527
PARTITION BY
  date OPTIONS ( partition_expiration_days=360 ) AS (
  SELECT
    oxford.*
  FROM
    bigquery-public-data.covid19_govt_response AS oxford
  WHERE
    alpha_3_code NOT IN ("GBR",
      "BRA",
      "CAN",
      "USA") )
```

Comment: Your query seems to be correct. Are you sure the select query returns a non empty result ?

Comment: MAX(date) seems to be **2021-09-10** which means all the data are expired right after table creation by **partition_expiration_days=360**;

Comment: @MazlumTosun Yeah, the select works…

Comment: @Jaytiger Let me check what you say, but it was the instruction from the Google lab, they say 360 days :(

Comment: @Jaytiger You were right, thank u so much! Also, the lab in broken I already reported Google, it's impossible to finished.

Comment: @Jaytiger, can you post the answer in the Answer section so that the community can easily find the answer to this question.

Comment: @AnjelaB, I've posted the answer. feel free to correct sentences to make them better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you run below query, it will create the table but you can't see any data in it.

```sql
#standardSQL
CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE `covid_598.oxford_policy_tracker_527`
PARTITION BY date OPTIONS ( partition_expiration_days=360 ) AS
SELECT oxford.*
  FROM `bigquery-public-data.covid19_govt_response.oxford_policy_tracker` AS oxford
 WHERE alpha_3_code NOT IN ("GBR", "BRA", "CAN", "USA");
```

It's because **expiration time** is set on each partion of the table.

When you try below query, you can see the max time of partition column `date` which is `2021-09-10`.

```sql
SELECT MAX(date)
  FROM `bigquery-public-data.covid19_govt_response.oxford_policy_tracker`;
```

PO is taking this course at the time of `2022-09-25` and all the data in
`oxford_policy_tracker` table already have passed the expiration day, i.e. `'2021-09-10' + 360 days`.

Therefore Bigquery will discard all the outdated data and nothing is put on new table.

Conclusion - Google Lab needs to update the course materials.